# Where is the line between Anaerobic and Aerobic?

Tags: cellular-respiration, anaerobic-respiration

I am well aware of traditional anaerobic respiration (lactic acid or alcohol produced - no Krebs cycle) and traditional aerobic respiration (O<sub>2</sub> is used at the end of the Citric acid cycle).

I am wondering how to classify respiration that uses the Citric acid cycle, but consumes a nitrite/ate or sulfite/ate instead of O<sub>2</sub>. Is that anaerobic or aerobic?

[image: NADH and Nitrite]

I could only find this image on Google image search catch but it said it was from http://lecturer.ukdw.ac.id/dhira/Metabolism/RespAnaer.html

Comment: http://toxics.usgs.gov/definitions/aerobic_biodegradation.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is based on a bit of confusion about electron acceptors that is very common and that drives microbiologists crazy. Energy (as ATP) is generated when electrons are moved from an electron donor to an electron acceptor. In respiration, the electron acceptor is inorganic -- oxygen for aerobic respiration or an inorganic molecule such as sulfate or nitrate for anaerobic respiration. Use of an organic molecule such as pyruvate as an electron acceptor is properly called fermentation. Both anaerobic respiration and fermentation are termed anaerobic because they don't use oxygen. Any introductory microbiology textbook will cover these concepts in detail, because they are important to understanding the metabolic diversity of bacteria. Brock Biology of Microorganisms is a good text.

Comment: A friend of mine checked 8 different introductory biology textbooks: 6 of them described respiration as using oxygen. However 2 of them did not specifically state oxygen as the terminal electron acceptor, which I am convinced is technically correct. Nitrogen as a terminal electron acceptor is an exception and not the rule, which is why it is so often overlooked in textbooks.

Answer (score 11):

Anaerobic respiration is a respiration where the final electron acceptor is different than oxygen. The final acceptor can be a less oxidizing than oxygen, like sulfate (SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>), nitrate (NO<sup>3-</sup>), or sulfur (S). For example bacteria that use sulfate are obligate anaerobs.

The Krebs cycle cannot take place in the absence of oxygen, although oxygen is not directly involved in the cycle. The oxygen is required for the electron transport chain, which oxidized NADH and FADH<sub>2</sub> back to NAD<sup>+</sup> and FAD<sup>+</sup>, which are involved in the four reduction reactions of the cycle.

Thus, aerobic respiration includes both Krebs cycle and final electron acceptor of oxygen, whereas anaerobic respiration does not.

Comment: I thought that NADH and FADH2 could be recycled using Nitrites - I edited in a diagram.

Comment: I still don't think that denitrifying bacteria will utilize Krebs cycle. Why would they do it anyways if no energy whatsoever comes from it?

Comment: One GTP (ATP) still comes out of one turn of the Krebs cycle. Although inefficient, there is still some sort of gain.

Comment: @jp89 All energy produced in the Krebs cycles comes from the electron transport chain, i. e. energy cannot be produced without oxygen.

Comment: "Most microbes respire (use an electron transport chain), although oxygen is not the only terminal electron acceptor that may be used. " - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_metabolism , see also; http://nitrificationnetwork.org/Introduction.php (Ctrl+F, electron transport chain)

Comment: @JoeHobbit It might be that denitrifying bacteria have Krebs cycle, but I think that this still classifies them as anaerobs. I will do more research and will let you know.

Comment: The Kreb cycle can indeed take place. You speak of the final electron acceptor being different than oxygen, but for what process? Surely you are referring to the electron transport chain? That would power the regeneration of NAD+ and FAD+. Thus anaerobic respiration includes the Kreb and the ETC.

Comment: @GerganaVandova Good One! I would suggest you to format it (just a little bit) by highlighting the bottom-line

Answer (score 4):

Agree that anaerobic **respiration** involves the electron transport chain and alternative terminal electron acceptors such as nitrate. However, respiring cells (whether respiring aerobically or anaerobically) can run the Krebs cycle. As long as there is a terminal electron acceptor, the NADH/FADH2 generated by the Krebs cycle can be oxidized back to NAD+ or FAD.

Comment: Welcome to biology.SE. Your answer, while interesting, does not address the question asked: "I am wondering how to classify respiration that uses the Citric acid cycle, but consumes a nitrite/ate or sulfite/ate instead of O2. Is that anaerobic or aerobic?"

Comment: The status of this question and its answers is completely messed up. This post has the correct answer - use of anything other than oxygen as a terminal electron acceptor is anerobic respiration. Cells using anerobic respiration will (normally) have a Krebs cycle. The answer from @Gergana Vandova is incorrect, despite its upvote score.

Answer (score 0):

While aerobic organisms during respiration use oxygen as a terminal electron acceptor, anaerobic organisms use other electron acceptors. These inorganic compounds have a lower reduction potential than oxygen, meaning that respiration is less efficient in these organisms and leads to slower growth rates than aerobes. Many facultative anaerobes can use either oxygen or alternative terminal electron acceptors for respiration depending on the environmental conditions.

Most respiring anaerobes are heterotrophs, although some do live autotrophically. All of the processes described below are dissimilative, meaning that they are used during energy production and not to provide nutrients for the cell (assimilative). Assimilative pathways for many forms of anaerobic respiration are also known:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_oxidizing_bacteria